# Why sub-package imports from parent package?

Tags: java, netbeans, import, package

I am creating a Java project in Netbeans.

I have a package called `MyPackage`. It has a class called `ClassA`.

I have two subpackages of `MyPackage` as `MyPackage.P` and `MyPackage.Q`

`MyPackage.P` has a class called `ClassB`.

The problem is, if I create an object of `ClassA` in `ClassB`, an import is added for `ClassA`.

```
import MyPackage.ClassA;
```

Isn't `ClassA` in the parent package? Why does it need to be imported?

PS: The problem is because in my large project, I have about 10 if these imports.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "subpackage"... The packages, even though in the file system, they are in folders under each other, are considered separate...

Comment: Each package is independent. There is no special behaviour which applies based on where the package is in the tree structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have two subpackages of MyPackage as MyPackage.P and MyPackage.Q

Now those are not subpackages of `MyPackage`. They are just different package, creating a completely different namespace. There is no such thing as *parent-child relationship* between packages. You can say that, they are just creating a logical grouping and nothing more. They will result in different directories created.

Comment: Actually, there is a sort of parent-child relationship, although only one-way from parent to child. If I have MyPackage and MyPackage.Constants, then I can reference Constants sub-package from code in MyPackage without doing an import and without having to fully qualify the package path (e.g. I can write: int circumference = 2 * radius * Constants.PI;)